# Missing Perspective Toolbar in SmartEdit in SPARTACUS 5.2 Version

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, smartedit

I am trying to setup SmartEdit with SPARTACUS 5.2, I tried following the document in the [SAP Help Portal > SAP Commerce Cloud, composable storefront > Integrations > SmartEdit > Integration](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/962112809f9a48f9b36aa05b208b3731/266db66bf8a7423193f30b5cacccd7ce.html?q=Smart%20Edit#loio70945ce2a31e4a44bcf7df86013ea117).

I am able to login but Perspective Toolbar is missing at the top. Also it will be in loading state as shown below.

[image]

Below is Spartacus changes

1. Added the below snippet in angular.json file

   ```
   {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "node_modules/@spartacus/smartedit/assets",
      "output": "assets/"
   }
   ```
2. Changed the spartacus-configuration.module.ts as below

   ```
   provideConfig(<SmartEditConfig>{
     smartEdit: {
       storefrontPreviewRoute: 'cx-preview',
       allowOrigin: 'localhost:9002',
     },
   }),
   ```
3. Added the URL in whiteListedStorefronts

   ```
   ["https://localhost:4200"]
   ```

But still, my SmartEdit shows the loading state.

I checked the network tab and I don't see `webApplicationInjector.js` call failing , It gives 200 OK.

Is there any other configuration I am missing? Thank you for your help